# Facebook-Graph-API get post by post id return an other post id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I query information of post id 104146902459712_115865294621206 but api return information of post id 104146902459712_115866081287794
Request:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/104146902459712_115865294621206?access_token=*******'
```

Response:

```
{
    "created_time": "2022-10-13T17:24:36+0000",
    "message": "⭕ Giày thu đông, Thắt lưng\n Các mẫu , hot nhất thu đông 2022\n\n❌Hàng shop tự chụp, nhận hàng kiểm tra thanh toán, có hỗ trợ đổi sz\n\n637 Lương Ngọc quyến Tp Thái Nguyên",
    "id": "104146902459712_115866081287794"
}
```

Why/When did it happen?